# how to remove invalid action error in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting `invalid action error` when I try to fetch data from server on button click .I click to the button to get data .bu I am getting this error

```
preview-fe7237b13d780dbf847da.js:1 ERROR Error: Effect "BanklistEffect.recipeFetch" dispatched an invalid action: [object Object]
    at reportInvalidActions (effects.umd.js:sourcemap:185)
    at verifyOutput (effects.umd.js:sourcemap:173)
    at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (effects.umd.js:sourcemap:231)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:78)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:102)
```

here is my code

click event handle

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kewril?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
fetchData(){
    this.store.dispatch(new FetchBankList());
  }
```

I am using `ngrx` for state management .I want to fetch this data and show on page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should return action from effect instead of Observable:

```js
import {Actions, Effect} from '@ngrx/effects';
import { switchMap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import * as BankActions from './bank.action';
import {Bank} from './bank.reducer';
@Injectable()
export class BanklistEffect {
  private url = 'https://biz.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/bankifsc/getlist';

  @Effect()
  recipeFetch = this.actions$
    .ofType(BankActions.FETCH_BANKLIST).pipe(
      switchMap((actions: BankActions.BankAction) => {
        return this.http.get<Bank[]>(this.url);
      }),
      map(res => new saveBanksAction(res)),
      catchError(err => console.log(err)),
  )
  constructor(private actions$: Actions,
              private http: HttpClient) {
  }
}
```

Comment: @user944513 Sure, please take a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bdrmgb. It's  should be refactored be you can see the idea